# Flex video player Seeking with RTMP?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, red5, rtmp

Am working in flex video player with **RTMP**.
My Question is.. 
How to skip the video file to the middle of a video without having to **download the whole file** using **RTMP**.

I have some basic questions in flex video player with RTMP.

1. Where i want to put the Video file(**FLV**). Red5 server location or any other folder.
2. Where i want to put the flex project
   out put file Red5 server or any
   other server like XAMPP.
3. How Can i skip    the frames in flex using **RTMP**(**red5**)..

Thanks in Advance...
Aswath

Answer (score 1):

It is easy:

stream.seek() call in flash. But don't forget to convert your video to mp4, or tag it with flvtool2

Comment: why it's needed  to convert a video to mp4, or tag it with flvtool2 ?